# How to access Rails environment variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm using dotenv and have API keys in my .env file. I would like to be able to use that api key in a javascript file, but am not sure how it would have access to Rails' environment variables. I'm not sure if this is correct, but I changed the end of the .js file to .js.erb and used my key as such (but it's not working):

```
var response = "http://bustime.mta.info/api/where/stops-for-location.json?lat=40.708727599999996&lon=-74.002798&latSpan=0.005&lonSpan=0.005&key=" + "<%= ENV['MTA_API_KEY'] %>";
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** When I ask for what the variable response is, I just get back, "http://bustime.mta.info/api/where/stops-for-location.json?lat=40.708727599999996&lon=-74.002798&latSpan=0.005&lonSpan=0.005&key=" (it's not rendering anything for where the key should go).

Comment: do you really have that environmental variable set?

Comment: can you output it in the console for example in the controller action that renders this js ?

Comment: @zmii - yes, it is set in my .env file as MTA_API_KEY=####################### . How would you recommend outputting it to the console from the controller (still learning Rails). Thanks.

Comment: `puts ENV['MTA_API_KEY']`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. I didn't need to concatenate between the request and my key variable:

```
var response = "http://bustime.mta.info/api/where/stops-for-location.json?lat=40.708727599999996&lon=-74.002798&latSpan=0.005&lonSpan=0.005&key=<%= ENV['MTA_API_KEY'] %>";
```

By keeping the key variable in with the string it worked. Thanks for all the help.